# What is the output voltage range of computer headphone ports?

Tags: computers, speakers

I made a simple microphone with amplifier which outputs 9V max signal. It's biased in the middle somewhere around 4.5V. I hooked the output of the circuit to the computer speaker audio in. I was wondering how much it can take or what is the recommended input and output voltage ranges of computer headphones and speaker ports?

Answer (score 5):

If it's a true microphone input, then it's looking for mV signals.  A "line in" port usually wants around 1 V RMS.  A "speaker" output port will be low impedance and have some power capability since it's intended to drive 4 or 8 Ohm speakers, usually to at least a few Watts.  Anything else is hard to guess.

Comment: Standard [line level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level) for consumer equipment is -10dBV or about 0.32V RMS. You might get up to 1 V RMS before clipping, since the input probably has around 20dB of headroom.